# git push fails on mounted davfs

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, filesystems

I am trying to mount a disc with a GIT repo using davfs2 on Ubuntu 15.10. If I mount the disc using SSH or NFS (in the same target dir), I have no problem. When using davfs2, there is apparently no problem with regular file access / creation / edit, but when I try to do git push, I get this error message:

```
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 367 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To /media/nas/all/repos/setup.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to '/media/nas/all/repos/setup.git'
```

I have tried setting use_locks to both 0 and 1 in davfs2.conf. It does not change the result.

Running 'strace git push' gives the following result. Please help me understand what I can do in order to make this work. git push seems to fail after some wait statements, as can be seen in the output. What can I do about this?

```
execve("/usr/bin/git", ["git", "push"], [/* 60 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x10f8000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a3000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=113621, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 113621, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd2687000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\0\26\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=448440, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2543880, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd2214000
mprotect(0x7f4dd2280000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4dd2480000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6c000) = 0x7f4dd2480000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\35\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=104824, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2199880, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd1ffa000
mprotect(0x7f4dd2013000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4dd2212000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f4dd2212000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3209\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=101232, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd2686000
mmap(NULL, 2206536, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd1ddf000
mprotect(0x7f4dd1df6000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4dd1ff6000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x17000) = 0x7f4dd1ff6000
mmap(0x7f4dd1ff8000, 6984, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd1ff8000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340`\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=142080, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2217232, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd1bc1000
mprotect(0x7f4dd1bd9000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4dd1dd9000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x18000) = 0x7f4dd1dd9000
mmap(0x7f4dd1ddb000, 13584, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd1ddb000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31680, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2128864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd19b9000
mprotect(0x7f4dd19c0000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4dd1bbf000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x6000) = 0x7f4dd1bbf000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\v\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1869392, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd2685000
mmap(NULL, 3972864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd15ef000
mprotect(0x7f4dd17af000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f4dd19af000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c0000) = 0x7f4dd19af000
mmap(0x7f4dd19b5000, 16128, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd19b5000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd2684000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd2683000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd2682000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f4dd2683700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4dd19af000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4dd1dd9000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4dd1bbf000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4dd1ff6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4dd2212000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f4dd2480000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7a9000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f4dd26a5000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd2687000, 113621)          = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f4dd26839d0)         = 4258
set_robust_list(0x7f4dd26839e0, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f4dd1bc6bb0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f4dd1bd1d10}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f4dd1bc6c40, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f4dd1bd1d10}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
open("/dev/null", O_RDWR)               = 3
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [PIPE], NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_DFL, [PIPE], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f4dd1624250}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x10f8000
brk(0x1119000)                          = 0x1119000
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=7216688, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 7216688, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd0f0d000
close(3)                                = 0
getcwd("/home/oivind/work/setup", 129)  = 24
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".git", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
open(".git", O_RDONLY)                  = 3
read(3, "gitdir: ../.git/modules/setup\n", 30) = 30
close(3)                                = 0
lstat("../.git/modules/setup/HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=23, ...}) = 0
open("../.git/modules/setup/HEAD", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "ref: refs/heads/master\n", 255) = 23
read(3, "", 232)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
lstat("../.git/modules/setup/commondir", 0x7ffcfcec3310) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("../.git/modules/setup/objects", X_OK) = 0
access("../.git/modules/setup/refs", X_OK) = 0
stat("../.git/modules/setup/gitfile", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5, ...}) = 0
stat("../.git/modules/setup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/home/oivind/work/setup", 129)  = 24
chdir("../.git/modules/setup")          = 0
getcwd("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup", 150) = 37
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
chdir("/home/oivind/work/setup")        = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/commondir", 0x7ffcfcec34a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/gitconfig", R_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/oivind/.config/git/config", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/oivind/.gitconfig", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/oivind/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=171, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
read(3, "[user]\n\tname = \303\230ivind Loe\n\temai"..., 4096) = 171
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 4096)            = 0
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/config", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/config", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=282, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
read(3, "[core]\n\trepositoryformatversion "..., 4096) = 282
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 4096)            = 0
chdir("/home/oivind/work/setup")        = 0
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=23, ...}) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/HEAD", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "ref: refs/heads/master\n", 255) = 23
read(3, "", 232)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/commondir", 0x7ffcfcec3480) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects", X_OK) = 0
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs", X_OK) = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/commondir", 0x7ffcfcec3470) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/gitconfig", R_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/oivind/.config/git/config", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/oivind/.gitconfig", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/oivind/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=171, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
read(3, "[user]\n\tname = \303\230ivind Loe\n\temai"..., 4096) = 171
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 4096)            = 0
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/config", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/config", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=282, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
read(3, "[core]\n\trepositoryformatversion "..., 4096) = 282
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 4096)            = 0
chdir("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup") = 0
chdir("../../../setup")                 = 0
getcwd("/home/oivind/work/setup", 129)  = 24
chdir("/home/oivind/work/setup")        = 0
stat("/home/oivind/work/setup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getcwd("/home/oivind/work/setup", 129)  = 24
chdir("/home/oivind/work/setup")        = 0
getcwd("/home/oivind/work/setup", 249)  = 24
lstat("/home/oivind/work/setup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
chdir("/home/oivind/work/setup")        = 0
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/commondir", 0x7ffcfcec3430) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/gitconfig", R_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/oivind/.config/git/config", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/oivind/.gitconfig", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/oivind/.gitconfig", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=171, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
read(3, "[user]\n\tname = \303\230ivind Loe\n\temai"..., 4096) = 171
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 4096)            = 0
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/config", R_OK) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/config", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=282, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
read(3, "[core]\n\trepositoryformatversion "..., 4096) = 282
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 4096)            = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=23, ...}) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/HEAD", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "ref: refs/heads/master\n", 255) = 23
read(3, "", 232)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/heads/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/heads/master", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "d89e132b2b99f3fe4fa74b940b442efa"..., 255) = 41
read(3, "", 214)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0x7ffcfcec2f40) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
stat("/media/nas/all/repos/setup.git", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=328, ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, 0x7ffcfcec2fd0) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 5 entries */, 32768)     = 136
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/heads", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/tags", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 4 entries */, 32768)     = 104
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=32, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=32, ...}) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "ref: refs/remotes/origin/master\n", 255) = 32
read(4, "", 223)                        = 0
close(4)                                = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin/master", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "b0df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e99"..., 255) = 41
read(4, "", 214)                        = 0
close(4)                                = 0
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/remotes/origin/master", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "b0df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e99"..., 255) = 41
read(4, "", 214)                        = 0
close(4)                                = 0
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/heads/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)     = 80
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/heads/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/heads/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/heads/master", O_RDONLY) = 4
read(4, "d89e132b2b99f3fe4fa74b940b442efa"..., 255) = 41
read(4, "", 214)                        = 0
close(4)                                = 0
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/tags/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/packed-refs", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=107, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=107, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
read(3, "# pack-refs with: peeled fully-p"..., 4096) = 107
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 4096)            = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/pack", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48
getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)     = 0
close(3)                                = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/info/alternates", O_RDONLY|O_NOATIME) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/d8/9e132b2b99f3fe4fa74b940b442efa06f222ee", F_OK) = 0
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/b0/df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e9996689ed9", F_OK) = 0
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/b0/df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e9996689ed9", F_OK) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {SIG_DFL, [CHLD], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, 0x7f4dd1624250}, {SIG_DFL, [], 0}, 8) = 0
pipe([3, 4])                            = 0
pipe([5, 6])                            = 0
pipe([7, 8])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f4dd26839d0) = 4259
close(8)                                = 0
read(7, "", 1)                          = 0
close(7)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(6)                                = 0
read(5, "008e", 4)                      = 4
read(5, "b0df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e99"..., 138) = 138
read(5, "0000", 4)                      = 4
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/b0/df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e9996689ed9", F_OK) = 0
stat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/packed-refs", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=107, ...}) = 0
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/b0/df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e9996689ed9", F_OK) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/b0/df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e9996689ed9", O_RDONLY|O_NOATIME) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=191, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 191, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 191)             = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/b0/df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e9996689ed9", O_RDONLY|O_NOATIME) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=191, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 191, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 191)             = 0
brk(0x1140000)                          = 0x1140000
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/info/grafts", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/shallow", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 524288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd2602000
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/d8/9e132b2b99f3fe4fa74b940b442efa06f222ee", F_OK) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/d8/9e132b2b99f3fe4fa74b940b442efa06f222ee", O_RDONLY|O_NOATIME) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=163, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 163, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 163)             = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/d8/9e132b2b99f3fe4fa74b940b442efa06f222ee", O_RDONLY|O_NOATIME) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=163, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 163, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 163)             = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/e8/702fd2aa79a3c02ce3fd8ed6ee0149d8dbab6c", O_RDONLY|O_NOATIME) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=163, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 163, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 163)             = 0
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/hooks/pre-push", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(4, "009ab0df467a4830d631512dee7de9b6"..., 154) = 154
write(4, "0000", 4)                     = 4
pipe([3, 6])                            = 0
fcntl(6, F_GETFD)                       = 0
fcntl(6, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
mmap(NULL, 8392704, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd070c000
mprotect(0x7f4dd070c000, 4096, PROT_NONE) = 0
clone(child_stack=0x7f4dd0f0bff0, flags=CLONE_VM|CLONE_FS|CLONE_FILES|CLONE_SIGHAND|CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SYSVSEM|CLONE_SETTLS|CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID, parent_tidptr=0x7f4dd0f0c9d0, tls=0x7f4dd0f0c700, child_tidptr=0x7f4dd0f0c9d0) = 4262
pipe([7, 8])                            = 0
pipe([9, 10])                           = 0
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f4dd26839d0) = 4263
close(10)                               = 0
read(9, "", 1)                          = 0
close(9)                                = 0
close(7)                                = 0
close(4)                                = 0
access("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects/b0/df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e9996689ed9", F_OK) = 0
write(8, "^b0df467a4830d631512dee7de9b61e9"..., 42) = 42
write(8, "d89e132b2b99f3fe4fa74b940b442efa"..., 41) = 41
close(8)                                = 0
wait4(4263, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4263
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4263, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
read(3, remote: error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument        
remote: fatal: failed to write object        
"0028", 4)                      = 4
read(3, "unpack unpack-objects abnormal e"..., 36) = 36
write(2, "error: unpack failed: unpack-obj"..., 51error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
) = 51
read(3, "0028", 4)                      = 4
read(3, "ng refs/heads/master unpacker er"..., 36) = 36
read(3, "0000", 4)                      = 4
futex(0x7f4dd0f0c9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 4262, NULL) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
close(-1)                               = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=4259, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
close(5)                                = 0
wait4(4259, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 4259
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/HEAD", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=23, ...}) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/HEAD", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "ref: refs/heads/master\n", 255) = 23
read(3, "", 232)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
lstat("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/heads/master", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=41, ...}) = 0
open("/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/refs/heads/master", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "d89e132b2b99f3fe4fa74b940b442efa"..., 255) = 41
read(3, "", 214)                        = 0
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "To /media/nas/all/repos/setup.gi"..., 34To /media/nas/all/repos/setup.git
) = 34
write(2, " ! [remote rejected] ", 21 ! [remote rejected] )   = 21
write(2, "master -> master", 16master -> master)        = 16
write(2, " (", 2 ()                       = 2
write(2, "unpacker error", 14unpacker error)          = 14
write(2, ")", 1))                        = 1
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2570, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f4dd26a2000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2570
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f4dd26a2000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/git.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "error: failed to push some refs "..., 68error: failed to push some refs to '/media/nas/all/repos/setup.git'
) = 68
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: I would run a series of tests to confirm that you can create a variety of files under `/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects`. It doesn't look like a permissions problem, but can't be sure.  Check that you can create files with modes `0444`, `0777` etc.

Comment: Nothing should be wrong with `/home/oivind/work/.git/modules/setup/objects`. I have a script that can switch my git repos `/media/nas/all` between being mounted through davfs and nfs, and if I switch to nfs, the commits always goes through. So there is no corruption or access problem in my local folders. I will try to do as you said in the mounted folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing all files on mounted disc to 777 solved this for me. If anyone else has a less intrusive way of testing, that would be great to see!